# Convert rotation to points array for a SVG Path

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a path that is basically a rectangle with 4 points. I rotate it by adding `transform="rotate(45)"`. Now I need to get coords of each corner point of the rotated path relatively to the container.

Probably it should be not rotation at all, but calculating a new `d` value with some algorithm for the path then setting it and making path look like it was rotated.

Please advise.

Comment: To calculate new coordinates for `d`: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195141/rotating-2d-coordinates

Comment: Not quite sure if the snap-framework tag should be snap.svg. If you are using snap.svg.js you can probably use snap.path.map http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Snap.path.map with a Snap matrix that has been rotated.

Comment: @Ian do you mind putting it as an answer so that I could mark it as a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert a path string by using the Snap.path.map() method. [Docs](http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Snap.path.map).

So using a matrix (eg Snap.matrix().rotate(45)), you can then pass it along with your path string to the Snap.path.map( myPath, myMatrix ); and it should convert it for you.